# Convert the XPath gotten from browser to usable XPath for Scrapy

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

This is a problem that I always have getting a specific XPath with my browser.

Assume that I want to extract all the images from some websites like Google Image Search or Pinterest.  When I use `Inspect element` then use `copy XPath` to get the XPath for an image, it gives me some thing like following :

```
//*[@id="rg_s"]/div[13]/a/img
```

I got this from an image from Google Search.   When I want to use it in my `spider`, I used `Selector` and `HtmlXPathSelector` with the following XPaths, but they all don't work!

```
//*[@id="rg_s"]/div/a/img
//div[@id="rg_s"]/div[13]/a/img
//[@class="rg_di rg_el"]/a/img #i change this based on the raw html of page 
#hxs.select(xpath).extract()
#Selector(response).xpath('xpath') 
.
.
```

I've read many questions, but I couldn't find a general answer to how I can use XPaths obtained from a web browser in Scrapy.

Comment: Why down vote? is this question duplicate? or whats wrong with that? i like to hear about any proposition!

Comment: Have not downvoted, but I guess the downvote was due to the "broad" style of the question "how can i use this xpathes in scrapy".

Comment: @kjhughes thanks for attention i know its because I am in a hurry!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually it is not safe and reliable to blindly follow browser's suggestion about how to locate an element.

First of all, XPath expression that developer tools generate are usually absolute - starting from the the parent of all parents - `html` tag, which makes it being more dependant on the page structure (well, `firebug` can also make expressions based on `id` attributes).

Also, the HTML code you see in the browser can be pretty much different from what Scrapy receives due to asynchronous nature of the website page load and javascript being dynamically executed in the browser. `Scrapy` is not a browser and "sees" only the initial HTML code of a page, before the "dynamic" part.

Instead, inspect what Scrapy really has in the response: open up the [`Scrapy Shell`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/shell.html#scrapy-shell), inspect the response and debug your XPath expressions and CSS selectors:

```
$ scrapy shell https://google.com
>>> response.xpath('//div[@id="myid"]')
...
```

---

Here is what I've got for the google image search:

```
$ scrapy shell "https://www.google.com/search?q=test&tbm=isch&qscrl=1"
In [1]: response.xpath('//*[@id="ires"]//img/@src').extract()
Out[1]: 
[u'https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRO9ZkSuDqt0-CRhLrWhHAyeyt41Z5I8WhOhTkGCvjiHmRiTSvDBfHKYjx_',
 u'https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQpwyzbW_qsRenDw3d4wwpwwm8n99ukMtLCVaPiTJxyviyQVBQeRCglVaY',
 u'https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSrxtoY3-3QHwhjc5Ofx8090uDYI8VOUbi3gUrd9USxZ-Vb1D5pAbOzJLMS',
 u'https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTQO1A3dDJ07tIaFMHlXNOsOnpiY_srvHKJE1xOpsMZscjL3aKGxaGLOgru',
 u'https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQ71ukeTGCPLuClWd6MetTtQ0-0mwzo3rn1ug0MUnbpXmKnwNuuBnSWXHU',
 u'https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRZmWrYR9A4W97jpjhtIbyUM5Lj3vRL0vgCKG_xfylc5wKFAk6UB8jiiKA',
 ...
 u'https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRj08jK8sBjX90Tu1RO4BfZkKe5A59U0g1TpMWPFZlNnA70SQ5i5DMJkvV0']
```

Comment: Hey thanks for explanation So is the result of `response.xpath('//div[@id="myid"]')` usable for scrapy?

Comment: @Kasra glad to help, it is just an example to demonstrate the syntax.

Comment: So can you please do this for an google image search? when instead of `google.com` i passed the url of image search it goes to shell but it doesn't show the prompt sing (>>>) and after enter it gets out from shell!

Comment: @Kasra you need to put the URL in quotes: `$ scrapy shell "https://www.google.com/search?q=test&tbm=isch&qscrl=1"`.

Comment: @Kasra please check the update - added a google image search example.

Answer (score 1):

The XPath generated from an insertion point in a browser is bound to be brittle because there are many different possible XPath expressions to reach any given node, JavaScript can modify the HTML, and the browser doesn't know your intentions.

For the example you gave,

```
//*[@id="rg_s"]/div[13]/a/img
```

the 13th `div` is particularly prone to breakage.

Try instead to find a uniquely identifying characteristic closer to your target.  A unique `@id` attribute would be ideal, or a `@class` that uniquely identifies your target or a close ancestor of your target can work well too.

For example, for Google Image Search, something like the following XPath

```
//div[@id='rg_s']//img[@class='rg_i']"
```

will select all images of class `rg_i` within the `div` containing the search results.

If you're willing to abandon the copy-and-paste approach and learn enough XPath to generalize your selections, you'll get much better results.     Of course, standard disclaimers apply about changes to presentation necessitating updating of scraping techniques too.  Using a direct API call would be much more robust (and proper as well).