# Python 3.4.0 -- xpath -- gets me empty list

Tags: python, xml, xpath, lxml

Trying to retrieve data from Ukrainian dictionary online everything works fine with:

```
url= "http://www.toponymic-dictionary.in.ua/index.phpoption=com_content&view=section&layout=blog&id=8&Itemid=9"
page = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
pageWritten = page.read()
pageReady = pageWritten.decode('utf-8')
xmldata = lxml.html.document_fromstring(pageReady)
text1 = xmldata.xpath('//p[@class="MsoNormal"]//text()')
```

But nothing works out with another link:

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse, parse_qs, urlencode

url = 'http://sum.in.ua/?swrd=автор'
parsed_url = urlparse(url)
parameters = parse_qs(parsed_url.query)
url = parsed_url._replace(query=urlencode(parameters)).geturl()
page = urllib.request.urlopen(url)

pageWritten = page.read()
pageReady = pageWritten.decode('utf-8')
xmldata = lxml.html.document_fromstring(pageReady)
text1 = xmldata.xpath('//div[@itemprop="articleBody"]')
```

It gets me an empty list.
Xpath is fine, while I double-checked it with Xpath Helper in Chrome.

Any ideas?

Comment: There is no such `<div>` in the HTML loaded from the URL. The *browser* can be served different HTML based on headers, or JavaScript could have altered the object tree.

Comment: The URL redirects to http://sum.in.ua/s/[.avtor.] which contains no results.

Comment: the Xpath  from browser perspective is different from another xml and html parsers , for more detail read this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29220031/convert-the-xpath-gotten-from-browser-to-usable-xpath-for-scrapy

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thanks second time, but is there the other way to deal with  either Ukrainian symbols in URL or XPath itself?

Comment: @KhrystynaSkopyk: you misunderstand me; this is nothing to do with encodings. The returned page simply doesn't contain the element you are looking for; the XPath expression is otherwise fine.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Here http://sum.in.ua/s/avtor and sum.in.ua/s/[.avtor.] The former leads to what is needed, the latter - to nothing. I believe, the second link was created after You helped me in encoding/decoding it.

Comment: @KhrystynaSkopyk: ah! there is actually a small bug in my previous answer.

Comment: @KhrystynaSkopyk: corrected my [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29436298) to add `doseq=True`; the `parse_qs()` result always uses lists for the values (sequences) and you need to explicitly tell `urlencode()` to support that style. Mea Culpa!

Comment: @KhrystynaSkopyk: That bug was the underlying issue for your question here. I'll dupe this to your previous question to indicate this; feel free to delete it if you feel it is not otherwise useful.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Saw your correction) Thank you so much, but I feel bad to say that it still gives an empty list(

Comment: @KhrystynaSkopyk: the code works for me, now, actually.

Comment: @KhrystynaSkopyk: https://gist.github.com/mjpieters/0a72eaf8332da9c4166f

Comment: @MartijnPieters Unbelievable) IT WORKS:) There are not enough thanks I want to give You)